# Php includes and images not working for Rewritten urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

After editing htaccess file for the short urls ,now my page has broken and php included files and images are not working,

This is my htaccess in the public_html

```
 RewriteRule ^car/name/(.*)$ /car.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

All included files and images are in **/files** folder ,

Now the problem is when I visit

```
http://example.com/car.php?name=hundai
```

it works and everything is ok,

but the problem is with Rewritten url

```
http://example.com/car/name/hundai
```

It breaks all php files and images.
Can you please help a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteRule is  changing your URL http://example.com/car.php?name=hundai into http://example.com/car/name/hundai ,which means that files path is inside a directory it was not before. this means that any relative links in document will not work. To solve this You need to use an Html

[Base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) 
 tag inside the "head" of your document.

```
 <head>
 <base href="http://example.com/files/">
 </head>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfect like a bottle of beer :)