# htaccess rewrite rule only partially works

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a basic htaccess rewrite file, however I am unable to get one of the rules to work when it is similar to a previous rule.

My code is;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^gallery$ gallery.php
RewriteRule ^about-us/page-1$ page-1.php
RewriteRule ^about-us/page-2$ page-2.php
RewriteRule ^about-us$ about-us.php
```

gallery, page-1 and about-us all work, however page-2 does not.

Is there a way to get this to work?

I have tried a different order and if about-us is put first, neither page-1 or page-2 work

note: The redirect redirects to the page-2 however the included files (css, js etc) do not load

Comment: Not sure if it is the problem, but note that your rewrite conditions only apply to the first rule. You would need to repeat them before every rule if they should apply there.

Comment: For css and js file to work on the rewritten url, you need to add a base href to the head of your document, <base href="http://example.com/"> for more info, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739024/php-includes-and-images-not-working-for-rewritten-urls/29739054#29739054

Comment: Thank you @Starkeen - I had forgotten this line of code for page-2 but had included it in page-1

Comment: @Gunaseelan your solution also worked after I had added the base href tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /about-us/page-2$ 
RewriteRule .* page-2.php [NC,L]    
RewriteRule ^gallery$ gallery.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/page-1$ page-1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ about-us.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change the results either.

Comment: Thanks for your second attempt, it still doesn't work for me though

Answer (score 1):

Add `[L,NC,QSA]` for the below 2 lines

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/page-1$ page-1.php
RewriteRule ^about-us/page-2$ page-2.php
```

Thus the modified .htacces will look like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^gallery$ gallery.php
RewriteRule ^about-us/page-1$ page-1.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^about-us/page-2$ page-2.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ about-us.php
```

As Starkeen said in comment, For css and js file to work on the rewritten url 
add the below code to head of your document.

```
<base href="yoursitename.com/">;
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve my problem - I have added a note above to further explain my problem